# Upgrading mongo search from runCommand to find using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using a Java driver to run some mongo text searches.
An example of my previous code is (where values is a String passed in):

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("testCollection");
//create the basic object
DBObject searchCmd = new BasicDBObject();
//create the search cmd
searchCmd.put("text", "testCollection"); // the name of the collection (string)
// define the search word
searchCmd.put("search", value); // the term to search for (string)
// define the return values
searchCmd.put("project", new BasicDBObject("score", 1).append("name", 1).append("path", 0).append("_id", 0));
// get the results
BasicDBObject commandResult = db.command(searchCmd);
// Just out the results key
BasicDBList results = (BasicDBList) commandResult.get("results");
```

then I loop over the "results" and I get for each it score by

```
// Get the number ii
BasicDBObject element = (BasicDBObject) results.get(ii);
// Now get the score
double score = (double) element.get("score");
```

I want to upgrade to use find since that seems the way 2.6 and later prefers it. So far I have:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("testCollection");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.append("$text", new BasicDBObject("$search", value));
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
```

However, I am not sure how to get the score.
I tried doing something like:

query.append("score", new BasicDBObject("$meta", "textScore"));

But this does not work. I would like to be able to get the name and the score so that I can then insert them into a new collection that will also hold the score.

I can get the name easily by:

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) 
{
DBObject next = cursor.next();
String name = next.get("name").toString();
}
```

But how do I get the score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this interesting page: http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/

it appears that find can take a second DBObject which has the fields.

I created a new object:

```
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
fields.append("score", new BasicDBObject("$meta", "textScore"));
```

and I am calling find using:

```
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query, fields);
```

and now I can get the score the same way I can get the name.

Comment: If your question is answered you can even accept your own post to show others that your solution works.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to wait a couple of days to do that.

Comment: I am using the mongo java driver 3.0 but there is no find() function which takes two bson objects. Any alternative to that?